# Getting a data from mysql db session store using node.js

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, session

I am using mysql db for session store for node.js and as an admin I want to kill the user's session when I want to. The way to do this is by deleting the session using session Id. on the database session store has the following attribute as shown in the image but my focus is parsing the data cell.

Since I can't use

> req.session.destroy()

which works for only the session which currently logged in so I have to parse the data cell to know more on about user.

But while parsing the row of db it is quit easy until data cell but data cell contains odd characters can't deal with.
For example for the data cell as follows I need to get the username as admin ,price as 0,items as {},

with the data cell a json like thing like this

```
[
  {
    "session_id": "6HNfH0LRs-lxN4vi6TY6DBFcv6A_X9g4",
    "data": "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"username\":\"admin\",\"price\":0,\"items\":{}}"
  }
]
```

Any suggestion how to do that

so the database looks like this 
[image]